# I need to access a variable outside of the function it is currently in. (JavaScript & NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am aware that JavaScript won't let me use `var result` outside of the function `app.get`. No matter how much I wrap my head around it, I can't seem to find a solution.

I need to access `var result` in the function `app.post` but its currently in the function `app.get` and has to stay inside of `app.get` because it is full of random numbers and having it inside of `app.get` lets me generate new random numbers every time I refresh the page... Here is the code:

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
 var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);

 var firstNumber = random ? (Math.random() * (10000) - 5000).toFixed(2) : (Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) - 50);
 var secondNumber = random ? (Math.random() * (10000) - 5000).toFixed(2) : (Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) - 50);
 var operations = random ? ["+", "-"] : ["*", "/"];

 var randomOperation = operations[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
 var expression = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber;
 var resultNotInterger = eval(expression);
 var result = Number(resultNotInterger).toFixed(2);

response.render("index.ejs", {
firstNumber: firstNumber,
secondNumber: secondNumber,
randomOperation: randomOperation,
result: result
   });
});



app.post("/", function(request, response) {
 var clientResponse = Number(request.body.clientResponse).toFixed(2);
 var machineResponse =
 response.redirect("/");
 console.log(result);
 });
```

Is there any genius out there that could solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know you could declare a variable inside a function"global", sorry for the inconvenience, but would you tell me where to put it please? I am still learning.

Comment: the problem is that if I put the variables in a global scope the random numbers will stay the same when I refresh the page, the only way to randomize the numbers again in that case is to restart the server. If I put it in "app.get" then the numbers do randomize every time the website is refreshed, but I can't access any data from there anywhere outside that function such as in the function "app.post".

Comment: @WiseEye What exactly you want to achieve from generating random numbers in "app.get" when you can declare a function to get it done as much time you want without refreshing the page.

Comment: @AbuSufian There is no keyword 'global' in JavaScript.

Comment: You can reassign the global variable every time the `get` route is used. Then use it in the `post` route.

Comment: @WiseEye "*I need to access `var result` in the function `app.post`*" - and what value do you expect it to have? The random-generated one from the last `get` request? What if someone does a post request before anyone doing a get request? And what do you even need the result for, what is your application doing? The most sensible solution might be to modify the client code so that it fetches a result using get and the passes it to the post request as a parameter, so that each client manages their "own" result.

Comment: @Bergi It looks like this is some kind of math quiz, and the data is a random formula. If you allow the client to send the parameters back, they could send a different question than the one that was posed.

Comment: @Barmar It might be a quiz, but there's not enough information in the question to understand how the flow should work. Why is the result sent to the client already? What does the client do? What is the post endpoint supposed to do? What would happen if there are multiple clients?

Comment: @Barmar yes it is a math quiz, I need to be able to compare the result generated by the computer with the result written by the client. I need to know if it was the right answer or not. Once the response is written sent by the client, I want another randomly generated equation (math problem) to appear, and the whole process repeats

Comment: @Begi you are right in the sense that it is wired the response is put there, it is for me to copy and paste into the response input (where the client will type the response) so I can quickly check if my code is recognizing whether or not it is correct. Once the code works, I will remove the answer of the equation from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the random number generation part is independent of the get request. You can always move that to a separate function an call it from both routes like this:

```
function getRandomNumbers() {
 var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);

 var firstNumber = random ? (Math.random() * (10000) - 5000).toFixed(2) : (Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) - 50);
 var secondNumber = random ? (Math.random() * (10000) - 5000).toFixed(2) : (Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) - 50);
 var operations = random ? ["+", "-"] : ["*", "/"];

 var randomOperation = operations[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
 var expression = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber;
 var resultNotInterger = eval(expression);
 var result = Number(resultNotInterger).toFixed(2);

 return {
   firstNumber,
   secondNumber,
   randomOperation,
   result,
 }
} 

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
   const {
     firstNumber,
     secondNumber,
     randomOperation,
     result,
   } = getRandomNumbers();

   response.render("index.ejs", {
     firstNumber: firstNumber,
     secondNumber: secondNumber,
     randomOperation: randomOperation,
     result: result
   });
});


app.post("/", function(request, response) {
 const { result } = getRandomNumbers();
 var clientResponse = Number(request.body.clientResponse).toFixed(2);
 var machineResponse =
 response.redirect("/");
 console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The problem I see is that, even though it does access a "result" I think it is another randomly generated result. The "result" of the app.get does not match with the "result" app.post console.logs. Any way to fix this? Thanks